# Linux APNS server which cert should I create?

Tags: ios, linux, push-notification, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am going to use a linux server for push notifications.

Is the following correct?

1. Generate a CSR of the **linux** server
2. Upload the file to Apple to generate a cert
3. Change this cer to pem and then conbine with my private key pem of linux
4. Use the combined pem in my code

Is this correct? Since I get confused by the Apple document, I can now only test push notifications in my mac book, and can't test on other servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to generate the CSR on your linux server.
You can use the `pem` or `p12` file you created (using your mac book) on any server.
If your code works when you test it on your mac book, it will work on any server. You just have to copy the `pem` or `p12` file to that server.

Comment: So I have to install the p12 to the linux server?

Comment: @RicoChan You have to copy either the p12 or pem (depending on which of them your code uses) to the linux server.